# In memory redis server for test

Tags: node.js, redis, mocha.js, integration-testing

I am writing integration tests for my NodeJS application that connects to a Redis cluster. The test framework I use is Mocha. Is it possible to setup Redis as an in-memory database which I can use to only test which then wipes away all my keys when the test is done?

Comment: i dont see why not?what problem are you having?

Comment: My app also tries to connect to mongodb. For running my integration tests, since I can't rely on an actual mongodb installation, I was able to use mongodb-memory-server package that lets me install, start and stop a mongodb server all during my build.
How do I do that for redis?

Comment: so you want a mock redis server right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 3):

Check this out

https://github.com/mhassan1/redis-memory-server : Redis Server for testing. The server will allow you to connect your favorite client library to the Redis Server and run parallel integration tests isolated from each other.